# TYPO3 6.2 DB Error: "exec_SELECTquery" while browsing in backend

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Every time I click on any page in the backend I get 6 DB Errors, that look very similar to this one, in total 3 different SELECT errors for the table `lawyer` and 3 for the table `student`:

```
caller  TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\DatabaseConnection::exec_SELECTquery
ERROR   Table 'db_lawclinic47.tx_lcapp_domain_model_lawyer' doesn't exist
lastBuiltQuery  SELECT uid FROM tx_lcapp_domain_model_lawyer 
WHERE pid=24 AND tx_lcapp_domain_model_lawyer.deleted=0 
AND (tx_lcapp_domain_model_lawyer.t3ver_state <= 0 OR
tx_lcapp_domain_model_lawyer.t3ver_wsid = 0) LIMIT 1

debug_backtrace     require(25/typo3/sysext/recordlist/mod1/index.php),25/typo3/mod.php#32 // 
TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\RecordList->main#31 // 
TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\RecordList\AbstractDatabaseRecordList->generateList#332 // 
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\DatabaseConnection->exec_SELECTgetSingleRow#410 // 
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\DatabaseConnection->exec_SELECTquery#406 // 
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\DatabaseConnection->debug#305
```

Those tables really don't exist because I renamed some and deleted some...and my webpage is working fine, so somehow those new tables are used, but there seems to be something old that is trying to select from the old tables and I have no idea what it could be and how to find it and get rid of it. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extension installed (probably with key `lcapp`) that requires these tables. If you don't need that functionality any longer, you should uninstall that extension in the Extension Manager.

Also, if the database was manipulated by some other tool than TYPO3 itself, you should check the database structure in the Install Tool. It can tell you about missing tables, fields that are not as specified and so on.

The database definitions for an extension are stored in the file `ext_tables.sql` in root of the extensions install directory, the Install Tool compares against these definitions.

Comment: to the first part: I need that extension, so uninstalling it doesn't sound like an option.
To the second part:
I checked the structure and it give me a loot of entries like `There are 88 records pointing to this missing or deleted record; [tx_lcapp_domain_model_...][1]`
Third part: ext_tables.sql is correct - there the tables that are missing also don't exist...as they should.
So now the question is, how can I delete all those records with missing records without having to find each one in the db manually...?

Comment: @Cold_Class If you need this extension, you should remove references to the unneeded tables from it, and also fields that are added to existing tables that reference those tables. Sounds like the table removal was just done in the database, not in the configuration. To remove them from the configuration, check the files directly in the folder `typo3conf/ext/lcapp`, and possibly the files under `typo3conf/ext/lcapp/Configuration/Tca`, and the extensions TypoScript configuration. There may be more places where the tables are referenced.

Comment: I solved most of the problem by deleting entries in certain tables, but your answer was helpful because I didn't know about that second part of your answer before :)